# Measure processing throughput in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a stream in java built as (anonimized some variables and classes):

```
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-stream-processing-application");
    config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "my-kafka-broker:6667");
    config.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    config.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

    KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> events = builder.stream("my-topic");

    events.foreach((key, value) -> {
        CustomClass instance = new CustomClass(value);
        for (AnotherCustomClass anotherInstance: someIterator) {
            anotherInstance(instance);
        }
    });

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);
    streams.start();
```

for kafka `0.10.0.0`:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-streams', version: '0.10.0.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '0.10.0.0'
```

My question is the following:

- How may I access the `KafkaStreams streams.metrics` inside the `foreach` loop? In order to read and / or print the proccesed messages throughput
- More generally: **How may I measure the proceesed messages throughput? Where processed means a message such that** `anotherInstance(instance)` **has been evaluated**

Answer (score 3):

Kafka Streams exposes all metrics via [JMX (Java Management Extensions)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html). You can check those metrics by using [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) or [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/). With those tools you can explore all metrics and graph them.

In order to check how many messages your application is processing have a look at that metric:

```
MBean: kafka.streams:type=stream-metrics,thread.client-id=[threadId]
Attribute: process-rate
```

It tells you average number of processed messages per second across all tasks.

Full list of Kafka Streams metrics can be found in [official documentation.](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#kafka_streams_monitoring)

Comment: kafka.stream.thread.process.rate -> this is specifying the rate for all number of threads, can I see the rate per thread? thanks